# C - fopen() doesn't work (returns null pointer)

Tags: c, fopen

Why does fopen() return a null pointer?

I'm trying to save the parameters after BRIDGE and after LAN (respectively 4 and 5) in cont_br and cont_lan, but fopen() doesn't work...

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

void read_file(char file[]) {

    char cont, *str, *ctrl_str;
    int x=0, cont_br, cont_lan;

    FILE *file_stream;

    if (file_stream = fopen(file, "r")) {

        while( !feof(file_stream) ) { //Check the file dimension
            fgetc( file_stream );
            x++;
        }
        x--;
        str = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * x+1);
        fseek(file_stream, 0, SEEK_SET); // Return at the beginning of the file
        fread(str, x, 1, file_stream);
        char delims[] = "#";
        char *result = NULL;
        result = strtok( str, delims);
        while (result != NULL) {
            if (result == "BRIDGE") { //Check the different "blocks" in the txt file
                result = strtok(NULL, delims);
                cont_br = atoi(result);
                printf("Number of bridges: %d\n", cont_br);
            }
            result = strtok(NULL, delims);
            if (result == "LAN") {
                result = strtok(NULL, delims);
                cont_lan = atoi(result);
                printf("Number of Lan: %d\n", cont_lan);
            }
            break; //
        }
    }
    printf("Error: can't open the file! errno: %d\n", errno);
    fclose(file_stream);
}

int main() {
    char file[] = "Config.txt";
    read_file(file);
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the Config.txt file:

```
BRIDGE#4#
LAN#5#
192.168.0.1
192.168.1.1
192.168.2.1
192.168.3.1
192.168.4.1
#
LINK#
B1:3000,L1
B1:3001,L2
B1:3002,L3
B2:3000,L4
B2:3001,L5
B3:3000,L1
B4:3000,L3
B5:3000,L2
B2:3002,L3
```

Comment: where is config.txt located ?

Comment: put this into debug folder if you running it in debug mode

Comment: I'm italian sorry if my english is incorrect :)

Comment: config.txt and read_file are in the same folder...

Comment: Print the `errno` with `strerror(errno)`.

Comment: print the path of `file` just before you call `fopen`, I guess it is not getting the path.

Comment: You are using feof incorrectly:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong/5432517

Comment: What is printed for `errno`?

Comment: Probably `fopen` never returned NULL; you only assumed it did, based on faulty logic elsewhere in your code. First of all, put `printf("Error: can't open the file! errno: %d\n", errno);` in an `else` block. Secondly, do not use `==` to compare strings; use `strcmp` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever fopen fails then print the error number (`errno`).

```
#include <error.h>
```

You should include the standard errno.h and print the value of `error` in your code. Then look at the error code and find the reason.

## Example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    errno = 0;
    FILE *fb = fopen("/home/jeegar/filename", "r");
    if (fb==NULL) {
        printf("Error %d \n", errno);
        printf("It's null");
    }
    else
        printf("working");
    }
```

This way if fopen fails then it will set the error number. You can find those error number lists in *[fopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html)*.

Comment: Error messages should be useful.  `fb = fopen( path, mode );  if( fb == NULL ) { perror( path ); ... `

Comment: `printf` can modify `errno`, so calling printf before using errno is a mistake.

Comment: how printf can modify errno?

Comment: `errno` is global. @Mr.32

Comment: perror("Config.txt") prints Success...

Comment: `perror` prints the error message.  When errno is 0, the related error message is "Success".  If you are doing `printf("its null")` followed by `perror`, then you are seeing the manifestation of printf changing errno.